# Json and lawnchair usage

Tags: json, lawnchair

i saw below example in lawnchair documentation,

```
var store = new lawnchair({name:'testing'}, function(store) {

    // create an object
    var me = {key:'brian'};

    // save it
    store.save(me);

    // access it later... yes even after a page refresh!
    store.get('brian', function(me) {
        console.log(me);
    });
});
```

i am not sure i understood it correctly or not, but based on my understanding, i wrote code like this, (name,dtime,address are variables with value)

```
db = Lawnchair({
            name : 'db'
        }, function(store) {
            console.log('storage open');
            var formDetails = {
                    "candidateName" : name,
                    "DateTimeOfVerification" : dtime,
                    "ResidentialAddress" : address
            }

            store.save({key:"fdetails",value:formDetails});

            store.get("fdetails", function(obj) {
                alert(obj);
            });

        });
```

but, in alert i did not got value, i got "[object Object]".

1) how to store multi-attribute  json object in lawnchair

2) how to get that json object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
db = Lawnchair({name : 'db'}, function(store) {
    console.log('storage open');
    var formDetails = {
        "candidateName" : "Viswa",
        "DateTimeOfVerification" : "30/07/2012",
        "ResidentialAddress" : "3 The Road, Etcc...."
    }

    store.save({key:"fdetails", value:formDetails});

    store.get("fdetails", function(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
        alert(obj.value.candidateName);
        alert(obj.value.DateTimeOfVerification);
        alert(obj.value.ResidentialAddress)
    });
});
```

1) You are storing the formDetails structure correctly.

2) obj.value is the collection you are looking for

Had you added the `console.log(obj);` line into your code and then inspected the console you could probably have worked this out for yourself.